# Visual Studio Could not find a part of the path system.net.http while checking in to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a solution that compiles and runs fine.  However when trying to check it in to TFS I get the error :

`"Could not find a part of the path C:\pathToMyProjects\MyProject\packages\System.Net.Http.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll".`

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017 while the project was last checked in to TFS while being built in Visual Studio 2015 if that has anything to do with it.

I've removed System.Net.Http from references and Nuget packages.  Even when all are uninstalled I get the same error.  Any clues as to how I can figure out what the real issue is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you have is mainly caused when you're trying to check in files which is no longer exist on the machine.

> This will happen when TFS has some changes staged that no longer exist
>   on the file system. For instance, if you add some files in Visual
>   Studio (which adds them to the changes list), delete them directly
>   from the file system, then attempt to check in the changes, it will
>   complain that it could not find the file(s).

Just try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Check if the file exists under the the specific path mentioned in the
  error message.
- Go to **Source Control Explorer** -> select these nonexistent files
  -> **Undo Pending Changes**. Or you can just left these files in the **Excluded Changes** list to not check in them.
- Re-install/upgrade Nuget packages in Package Manager Console:

  `PM > update-package System.Net.Http -r`
- **Uninstall** the `System.Net.Http` Nuget packages and remove the reference, then **reinstall** the [`System.Net.Http` Nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) and add the reference again.
- Clean and rebuild your whole solution, once that compiles and runs
  fine locally, then try to check in the changes again.
- Check if this issue also occurs on other VS machines, so we could
  know that whether it is related to the VS Environment or others.

Comment: Thanks Andy, you are the man.  I had tried many of those things but not the second bullet for using Source Control Explorer to Undo Pending Changes.  I didn't even know that existed.  After undoing each change the errors gave me I was able to check in just fine.  Kudos!

Comment: Worked fine for me.  I think I ended up with this issue as a result of upgrading packages 2x in a row without doing a Check-In in between.